IS there a term for "Leading from Below" in the context of japanese military history?
During the Interwar period and the 2nd World War (~1918-1945), there were many incidents where lower-ranking officers of the Japanese Army created situations that were meant to become either the Casus Belli with which a superior officer might manage to get a proper declaration of war or to otherwise force a specific reaction. Among those incidents would be the Mukden Incident (a false flag incident to justify the occupation of Manchuria). Still, numerous other incidents that increased tension might also fall under that umbrella of situations, as might situations that were crafted to create more unsavory results.
I find that such actions in English literature are often using the combination "Leading from Below" for such incidents that overstep established hierarchy and rights, but go unpunished or even seem to have gotten some sort of praise. This implies that there might be a Japanese term. However, it seems that Gekokujō (下克上 / 下剋上), while quite similar, might not always be the right term in the context, as it also can mean a junior-officer-coup as I understand it.
Is there a separate, maybe similar, term that describes leading from below in the sense of forcing/coercing superior commanders to take a specific action?
